# Adding "Estimated Shipping Date" to Success.phtml

Tags: checkout, shipping, frontend

So, I had some luck with embedding a backend attribute to each product (called ship_days) and have had success posting the variable through the following formula:

```
<?php   
        $days=array();
        $order_items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach($order_items as $item) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $day = number_format($product->getShipDays(),2,'.','');     
            $days[]=urlencode($day);
            $max=max($days);
        }
```

Which when echos provides the correct value depending on the products in cart (some SKUs have a ship_days variable of 3, others have 5) Iused the following output:

```
<?php echo date ('m/d/y', strtotime ( "+$max weekdays" ));  ?>
```

Which should have output 6/19/2015 when calculated on Friday the 12th (tested on a PHP Sandbox) but actually output 6/11/2015.  I also tried putting a PHP function but it seemed to slow down the processing of Success.phtml to the point where the page wouldn't load... what's the best way to accomplish this?

The function I tried embedding into Success.phtml is a function I use successfully in other files, but should I call that from a block or an external PHP script?  Function below:

```
function dateFromBusinessDays($days, $dateTime=null) {
  $dateTime = is_null($dateTime) ? time() : $dateTime;
  $_day = 0;
  $_direction = $days == 0 ? 0 : intval($days/abs($days));
  $_day_value = (60 * 60 * 24);

  while($_day !== $days) {
    $dateTime += $_direction * $_day_value;
    $_day_w = date("w", $dateTime);

    if ($_day_w > 0 && $_day_w < 6) {
      $_day += $_direction * 1; 
    }
  }

  return $dateTime;
}
```

Anyone have any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop the decimal places in the $day variable. The strtotime() function returns different results depending on whether or not whole numbers are used.

This gives the correct results:

```
<?php echo date ('m/d/y', strtotime ( "+5 weekdays" ));  ?>
```

This doesn't, which is what your code currently does assuming a shipping time of 5 days:

```
<?php echo date ('m/d/y', strtotime ( "+5.00 weekdays" ));  ?>
```